# UIScrollView scrolling background image twice as quick

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

In XCode, I have written an app which uses a UIScrollView with a background image. Up until this morning everything was working fine, but for some reason now, when I scroll the scroll view, the background image is scrolling twice the amount of the scroll.

Hope this makes sense to anyone, as I cannot figure out what I have done

Comment: Did you change the `decelerationRate` of the scrollView?

Comment: I havn't changed anything that I am aware of. The background image is 1600 wide and and the content size of the scrollview is 1600. If I scroll to halfway across the scrollview, I am at the end of my image, as the image has scrolled twice the distance than I have srolled???

Comment: what does `NSLog("%@", NSStringFromCGRect(scrollView.contentSize));` return?

Comment: I've found the probem. It was because I was running the simulator in ios 4.2, not 4.3. How can I make sure it scrolls correctly in 4.2, 4.1 and 4.0 as well?

Comment: So in 4.3, it is working and not in 4.2? That's strange. Did you get a chance to execute the query. I am thinking the `contentSize` must've have changed.

Comment: It's strange. Runinng on ios simulator 4.3 and al is fine. Run it on 4.2 and below, I get the strange 2 times scroll. Also, I have just notices on another scroll view, that on 4.2 and below, the background images doesn't scroll, even though the content does.

Comment: I used : NSLog(@"Size : %@", NSStringFromCGSize(theScroller.contentSize)); and in both simulators 4.0 and 4.3 it returned 'Size : {1600, 430}' as expected. I need to get this fixed quite soon as my app is on sale, so people without the latest ios will be having problems. Thanks in advance

Comment: Any chance you can post relevant code as to how you are setting things up?

Comment: I put the image onto the scroller like this                img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ResultsScroller.png"];
    [resultsView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img]];

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've worked it out. I read a few other forums which had the same problem. I ended up adding a UIImage as a subview on my scroller, and set the image of that. It works fine now.

I suppose that may have been a bug up to 4.3 and now Apple have fixed it.